# Wunderground API - Historical Forecasts?

Tags: wunderground

Is there a way to get historical forecasts from the wunderground API? For instance, find out the predicted high temperature 5 days from an arbitrary date in the past?

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the Wunderground website, under Key Settings, there is a spot to request access to history data, in the area where you purchase a key. Fill out the form, and you can expect a response within a couple days telling whether you have access to history data. Once you do, look under Documentation to find out how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can sign up for a developer account (free) and that gives you access to 500 calls/day or 10 calls/minute. You can use that to make calls to the history API and test it.

http://api.wunderground.com/weather/api